# Can you add thousands of records in a Data Table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatable

I'm trying to put the a Large records from my model to the Data Table. I'm using 64 bit pc ram but still shows an error:

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

I use this to pass the records to the list:

```
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        using (MVCPRACEntities db = new MVCPRACEntities())
        {
            List<AMSFR_APRR_INVOICE_HIST2> emplist = db.AMSFR_APRR_INVOICE_HIST2.ToList<AMSFR_APRR_INVOICE_HIST2>();
            return Json(new { data = emplist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe, the object in .NET allows you to use 2 GB of RAM space and your object seems more than that. Would like to know that what are you trying to do with this much data in real based scenario?

Comment: Not so related, but you should learn how to use pagination instead loading large amount of data from entity to `DataTable` at once. Which exact amount of data you want to add into `DataTable`?

Comment: If you want to have more than 2 GB size object, enable the setting by    `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`

Comment: @AkashKC which is a .net 4.5 thing IIRC.

Comment: @TanveerBadar : You mean available space for object or the setting?

Comment: The setting, I don't think it was available in .net 4.0 or earlier.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing out.